# How can I sort a Map[string]int by its values?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go

Given this code block

```
map[string]int {"hello":10, "foo":20, "bar":20}
```

I would like to print out

```
foo, 20
bar, 20
hello, 10
```

In the order of highest to lowest

Comment: As you may know, this situation requires an iteration on a map, which is not recommended because of the Big O matter.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Found the answer on Golang-nuts by Andrew Gerrand

You can implement the sort interface by writing the len/less/swap functions

```
func rankByWordCount(wordFrequencies map[string]int) PairList{
  pl := make(PairList, len(wordFrequencies))
  i := 0
  for k, v := range wordFrequencies {
    pl[i] = Pair{k, v}
    i++
  }
  sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(pl))
  return pl
}

type Pair struct {
  Key string
  Value int
}

type PairList []Pair

func (p PairList) Len() int { return len(p) }
func (p PairList) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].Value < p[j].Value }
func (p PairList) Swap(i, j int){ p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

For the original post, please find it here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/FT7cjmcL7gw

Comment: ... except `Less` is returning the wrong result. For reverse sort, use `>`.

Comment: @larsmans My bad! Thanks for pointing it out. I have instead used sort.Reverse to get the reverse results

Comment: Even better, I didn't even know about `sort.Reverse`. +1.

Answer (score 106):

There's a new sort.Slice function in go 1.8, so now this is simpler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{
        "something": 10,
        "yo":        20,
        "blah":      20,
    }

    type kv struct {
        Key   string
        Value int
    }

    var ss []kv
    for k, v := range m {
        ss = append(ss, kv{k, v})
    }

    sort.Slice(ss, func(i, j int) bool {
        return ss[i].Value > ss[j].Value
    })

    for _, kv := range ss {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", kv.Key, kv.Value)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/y1_WBENH4N

Comment: I don't like how the output isn't the map I began with

Comment: @hendry this answer is specifically in response to the format in the original question. In go1.12 you can just print the map and it'll be sorted, see the issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21095

Comment: almost perfect, I suggest handle elements with same value.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli how? Make them stable? Or sorted alphabetically? Pretty sure stability is impossible because Go randomizes map iteration order specifically to stop you relying on an ordering that is explicitly called out as not significant to the compiler. For alphabetical you can easily modify the anonymous function passed to sort.Slice

Comment: @voutasaurus easy, if ss[i].Value == ss[j].Value use the Key. This way you will always get the same order. If you run your example you can see that "yo" and "blah" are not always on the same position

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli that's not what I (or a textbook) mean when I say "stable" sorting. But yes sorting the keys alphabetically is possible, but it's not asked for in the question posted here.

Comment: @voutasaurus it's your code, do what you want with it. IMHO a sort function must return the same output for a given input at all times. Breaking the tie by comparing the keys is a very simple and effective way to do that.

Comment: There is also a [sort.SliceStable](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SliceStable) (also added in Go 1.8) that preserves the original order of the equal elements.

Comment: SliceStable is a fine function but it won't stabilize the order of a map. The map iteration order is randomized for a reason. If you want the same results every time it's better to use another tie-breaking element (as Tommaso suggests one could use the string itself).

Answer (score 24):

Sort keys first by value and then iterate map:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    counts := map[string]int{"hello": 10, "foo": 20, "bar": 20}

    keys := make([]string, 0, len(counts))
    for key := range counts {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool { return counts[keys[i]] > counts[keys[j]] })

    for _, key := range keys {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", key, counts[key])
    }
}
```

Comment: I am hot sure who is downvoting, probably those who don't read comparator function carefully. 
Also accepted answer does not produce the printout OP asked for but instead introduces new datastructure that has to be maintained in real code.
Here is the playground link for my answer https://play.golang.org/p/Y4lrEm2-hT5

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, simplest solution.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, since it does not need a struct.

Answer (score 19):

For example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sort"
)

func main() {
        m := map[string]int{"hello": 10, "foo": 20, "bar": 20}
        n := map[int][]string{}
        var a []int
        for k, v := range m {
                n[v] = append(n[v], k)
        }
        for k := range n {
                a = append(a, k)
        }
        sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(a)))
        for _, k := range a {
                for _, s := range n[k] {
                        fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", s, k)
                }
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SAYsU8U17P)

---

Output:

```
foo, 20
bar, 20
hello, 10
```

Comment: This assumes that the values don't have identities.

Comment: @newacct: It solves only the OP problem, not the general case ;-)

Comment: this solution is the one that worked for my case as well, simple to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I often need to sort a `map[string]int` of something I’m counting and have been using the following.

```golang
func rankMapStringInt(values map[string]int) []string {
    type kv struct {
        Key   string
        Value int
    }
    var ss []kv
    for k, v := range values {
        ss = append(ss, kv{k, v})
    }
    sort.Slice(ss, func(i, j int) bool {
        return ss[i].Value > ss[j].Value
    })
    ranked := make([]string, len(values))
    for i, kv := range ss {
        ranked[i] = kv.Key
    }
    return ranked
}
```

Use it to iterate over the keys in order of value

```
values := map[string]int{"foo": 10, "bar": 20, "baz": 1}

for i, index := range rankMapStringInt(values) {
    fmt.Printf("%3d: %s -> %d", i, index, values[index])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was dealing with a program that I created. In this program, I created a Map just like you, with `string` and `int`. Then I discovered like you that Go doesn't really have a built-in way to sort something like this. I read the other answers and didn't really like what I read.

So I tried to think about the problem differently. Go can use [sort.Ints](//golang.org/pkg/sort#Ints) with a slice. Also, Go can use [sort.Slice](//golang.org/pkg/sort#Slice) with a custom comparator. So instead of creating a Map of `string` and `int`, I created a `struct` of `string` and `int`. Then you can sort:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sort"
)

type file struct {
   name string
   size int
}

func main() {
   a := []file{
      {"april.txt", 9}, {"may.txt", 7},
   }
   sort.Slice(a, func (d, e int) bool {
      return a[d].size < a[e].size
   })
   fmt.Println(a)
}
```

This will not work for everyone, because maybe you will be forced to deal with a map someone else created. But it was useful for me. Good part is, unlike all the other answers, this one uses no loops.

Comment: Your answer answers a slightly different question. Please stick to the input structure (map) of the original question.