# How to sort a map[string]float64 by the float64 value?

Tags: sorting, go

I'm struggling to understand how to simply sort a `map[string]float64`. I had a look at [How to sort a Map[string]int by its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695346/how-to-sort-a-mapstringint-by-its-values), which suggests using a struct to do the sort, but I'm not sure how to do this when the `sort.Sort` func expects `func(i, j int)` and not `func(i, j float64)`.

For example, how would this be sorted?

```
data := make(map[string]float64)
data["red"] = 1.00
data["green"] = 3.00
data["blue"] = 2.00
```

I tried the following, but that only sorts by the `string` in the map, not the actual `float64`:

```
data := make(map[string]float64)
data["red"] = 1.00
data["green"] = 3.00
data["blue"] = 2.00

var keys []string
var values []float64
for key, cost := range data {
    keys = append(keys, key)
    costs = append(costs, cost)
}
sort.Strings(keys)
sort.Float64s(values)
for _, key := range keys {
    fmt.Printf("%s %v\n", key, data[key])
}
```

Comment: The `i` and `j` arguments are indices into the slice, not the actual value to sort. Please look at the examples in the [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package to see how to use it. You also probably want a `struct { key string, cost float64 }` to sort.

Comment: Ahhh that's what I was missing. Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects `int` instead of `float64` because `i, j` are indices to use on comparing and swapping elements in a slice.
I recommend you should use a new struct and implement the sort.Interface for it:

```
type MapData struct {
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

type MapSort []*MapData

func (m MapSort) Len() int {
    return len(m)
}
func (m MapSort) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return m[i].Value < m[j].Value
}
func (m MapSort) Swap(i, j int) {
    m[i], m[j] = m[j], m[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc for pointing out my mistake, here's what I'm using to sort successfully:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sort"
)

// round a float64 to 2 decimal places.
func round(n float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(n*100) / 100
}

type Pair struct {
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

type PairList []Pair

func (p PairList) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p PairList) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].Value < p[j].Value }
func (p PairList) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }

func main() {
    data := make(map[string]float64)
    data["red"] = 1.00
    data["green"] = 3.00
    data["blue"] = 2.00

    var i int
    sorted := make(PairList, len(data))
    for key, value := range data {
        sorted[i] = Pair{key, value}
        i++
    }
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sorted))
    for _, pair := range sorted {
        fmt.Printf("%s %v\n", pair.Key, round(pair.Value))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the built-in `append()` to append to a slice. `sorted = append(sorted, Pair{...})`